# C# How return a Color

Tags: c#, colors, return

- Hi, i would like to do this but i have an error (CS1955). Somneone can help me please. Thanks ;)

```cpp
private Color GetColor(UInt32 hex)
{
return Color(hex & 0xFF, (hex >> 24) & 0xFF, (hex >> 16) & 0xFF, (hex >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color is made using the static `Color.FromArgb()`.

```
private static Color GetColor(UInt32 hex)
{
    var intHex = (int)hex;
    return Color.FromArgb(intHex & 0xFF, (intHex >> 24) & 0xFF, (intHex >> 16) & 0xFF, (intHex >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```